# Jquery .val() doesn't work on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a textarea where user can type a comment and press enter to submit the comment and then after that the textarea's text should be cleared and the placeholder should appear so i used this function

```
<tr id="SC-1-Comment" style="background-color:white;">
<td colspan="2">
    <textarea id="id_COMMENT_to_POST-1" name="Comment" style="resize: none; vertical-align: middle;" placeholder="Leave a comment..." 
        onkeydown="
        if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) 
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            NEW_COMMENT('commentsinnerhtml-1', '1',document.getElementById('id_COMMENT_to_POST-1').value); 
            $('#id_COMMENT_to_POST-1').val('');
        }
        "></textarea>
</td>
```

In chrome and IE it works but in Firefox, it just ends up clearing the text and inserting a new line in the textarea and thus placeholder won't appear as there is a new line in the textarea.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're using jQuery.  Is there a reason you can't assign events the jQuery way?  Separate script from html?

Comment: I tried and it didn't work :/

Comment: `@` aren't valid characters in [ID selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). If this is a view, perhaps Razor, please include the resulting client-side markup. But, you also don't need to select the element the event is bound to -- `this.value`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski If this is HTML 5, the only character that isn't valid for the id attr is `space`. However, that doesn't mean special characters in an id attr work well with JavaScript without proper handling.

Comment: @BOSS Please give us the actual id generated by the MVC code.  Periods will not work in jQuery unless you're referring to a class.

Comment: @stevelove HTML5 is probably fine with them, but CSS Selectors aren't. And jQuery selectors are based on CSS rules.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski My mistake. I failed to notice your link was pointing to jQuery's selector documentation and assumed you were referring generally to the id attribute.

Comment: I just answered my own question and i found a solution please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it wasn't the DOM or anything, i just had to use a settimeout interval, i don;t know why but probably the web browser just needed a few milliseconds between the two operations.
and here is the new code

```
<tr id="SC-@ep.POST_ID-Comment" style="background-color:white;">
<td colspan="2">
    <textarea id="id_COMMENT_to_POST-@ep.POST_ID" name="Comment" style="resize: none; vertical-align: middle;" placeholder="Leave a comment..." 
        onkeydown="
        if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) 
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            var post = document.getElementById('id_COMMENT_to_POST-@ep.POST_ID').value;

            $('#id_COMMENT_to_POST-@ep.POST_ID').val('');

            setTimeout(function () {
            NEW_COMMENT('commentsinnerhtml-@ep.POST_ID', '@ep.POST_ID', post);
            },100);
        }
        "></textarea>
</td>
```

Comment: That's why you should read the basic of jquery, which is `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Comment: @Dorian_gd, how would that help?  The event is firing well after the document is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Try the vanilla JavaScript approach, keep it nice and simple.

```
document.getElementById("text-area-id").value = '';
```

Can't imagine why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @BOSS "Didn't work" isn't a problem description.  Tell us what happened, what didn't happen, and what error message you received.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5akRg/1/ Works fine for me. Perhaps you're doing something wrong with the DOM? More info, please

Comment: I just answered my own question and i found a solution please check it out.